# Changing CMOS battery for Hp Pavillon dm3t-1100 laptop

Tags: motherboard, bios, battery, laptop-repair, cmos

So started seeing that my computer clock date and time are ahead or behind. This computer is old so I think it's the battery. Had a few questions

1. If I don't change the battery will computer keep working just fix the time and date when I turn it on?
2. I removed the laptop battery so I use it straight from power. If I keep it plugged in and turn it off will it keep the CMOS battery good?
3. Will battery leak if I don't change the CMOS battery?
4. How do I change it? Where is it located and how easy is it to find and remove it?
5. Does this model uses special cmos battery or like a regular clock battery? Where can I find this type of battery?

Thanks

Comment: [NEW OEM FOR HP Pavilion dm3 dm3-1100 Series Battery - Cmos / Resume / RTC | eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-OEM-FOR-HP-Pavilion-dm3-dm3-1100-Series-Battery-Cmos-Resume-RTC-/264449233544)

Comment: 1 and 3 - they can leak if old but odds are the battery will not leak. Get the HP replacement battery or warranty-approved third party replacement and replace it. That is the best thing to do.

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXzFJnHE-7g) will show you how to tear it apart. I don't recommend using a drill, and I'd definitely watch the whole video before you touch the computer to make sure you know what you're getting into. 
@DavidPostill mentioned the battery to buy already. I'd just replace it and move on if it were me then all problems are resolved. :)

Comment: How do I find out where it is located on laptop? How do I find out which one to buy and how many? Not a big fan of Ebay or amazon as I don't trust resellers. Any good computer stores? Is it really a watch battery?

Comment: "Is it really a watch battery?"  Get the HP Docs and the Part numbers - one should be the battery identifier. That will tell you.

Comment: Thanks John but "Get the HP Docs and the Part numbers" where do I find part numbers or these documents? New to this? Is there a site or just google because hp tech support won't help I assume.

Comment: The manual should give you the HP number and generic number if one.  The HP support site for your model should have this (PDF) manual

Comment: I found an [ebay item](https://ebay.us/YbyRHD) showing the battery. It is a watch-type battery, but it's got an adapter with it, just like the first comment showed. A computer that old, your best bet is probably going to be Ebay or Amazon for the parts. @John is right. HP has your [manual](https://support.hp.com/ph-en/product/hp-pavilion-dm3-1100-entertainment-notebook-pc-series/4074357/manuals)

Comment: Just read the manual does not show it. Is there a way to find out what I need to buy and where the battery is located so I can just buy everything and open it when I have all the parts? Manual does not have drawings of what's inside and all parts names.

Comment: Try here:  http://tim.id.au/laptops/hp/hp%20pavilion%20dm3.pdf   Page 51  (RTC Battery part number 580845-001)

Comment: Will that work I  USA edition of laptop?

Comment: I searched the HP (US) Site and that manual came up as a close counterpart for the particular laptop.

Comment: Thanks that means parts are same I guess. Will computer still function if I dont change the batter or it wont turn on anymore?

Comment: The computer will turn on but (a) the clock will change time and (b) old batteries can and do leak over time.

Comment: Do you know if I can make my own? I read it's just a watch battery. Can I buy a watch battery and attach it to 2 wires with an electric tape? I do not know how to solder. Will this work?

Comment: Is there an answer here that satisfies you?

Comment: Sorry not used to how this forum works. They kind of all answer my questions as I had a few. Perhaps the one before my making your own questions. Thanks